# Get database field non null values which contain both null and not null

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a question related to query . I have a table in which a hava these field

```
Table : Videos
Fields : id , video_id , video_title_image_id , video_title_image
```

Now it is optional to have either video_title_image_id or video_title_image
Let suppose a have records like this

```
id     video_id      video_title_image_id video_title_image
1      rSKwjrqBhAA               2               NULL
2      rSKwjrqBhAA              NULL             image1.png  
...
```

Now i want to select only those having video_title_image not null
And i have done this

```
select  video_title_image
    from videos
where video_title_image != NULL
```

But it fetches no results
Any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are simple ways some of them are these

```
select  video_title_image
    from videos
where not isnull(video_title_image)
```

Or

```
select  video_title_image
    from videos
where video_title_image > 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
select  video_title_image
from videos
where video_title_image is not NULL
```

Comparing something to `null` will result in `unknown`. That is why you need to use the `is` operator to check for `null`.